# How to migrate from Oracle Exadata X4-2 database to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, exadata

1. What are the migration considerations that should be taken?
2. Is it better to have a new data model prepared beforehand fo BigQuery? Or move the data As-Is data model to bigquery first and then change the data model
3. Any key considerations to make
4. Any migration templates that can be used
5. Any other key suggestions please indicate as well

Answer (score 0):

1. for a one off migration, you can output Oracle tables to Cloud Storage (as csv, avro or parquet) and then perform an import from Cloud Storage.  This can be wrapped up within a script using the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest) and can make use of Cloud Composure if there is a need to orchestrate the load.  There are also several tools that can assist such as DataPrep and Data Flow, but each come at a cost and a learning curve.
2. To make use of BigQuery is it is likely that you'll want to remodel, rather then reuse Oracles schema.
3. You really need to understand the data you are starting with, the BigQuery environment that will support your business need going forward and size and complexity of the migration.  Take a look at this [Oracle to BigQuery migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/static/architecture/dw2bq/oracle/oracle-bq-migration-guide.pdf)
4. Migrations tend to be business/ data specific, so no templates that I am aware of
5. Understand your data well and restructure to make use of BigQuery strengths (such as nested and repeated data).  Make sure you utilise partitions and clusters to suit your business querying need. Avoid the need for joins where you can.  Shift design consideration away from storage cost and towards query data structure and query optimisation for performance and query cost benefit